# Can I use Pages like a Wiki

Tags: pages, wiki

I would like to have a central place to keep my notes for projects. Does it make sense to use pages like a Wiki?

Comment: Why not create your own private post type and set the required capabilities to `manage_options` or similar, so it's only viewable by admins, or are you wanting to show notes in view of regular visitors?

Comment: Doesn't "wiki" imply public/group content contribution? If these are your personal notes, why use a "wiki"?

Comment: +1 - That was my point, if these are private notes i can't think why you'd choose to use pages.

Comment: I like the Wiki format of document creation and linking. Not really collaboration.

Comment: See some longer answers @ http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31119/options-for-wiki-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Not really, why not use something like tiddlywiki.