# Options for Wiki WordPress

Tags: wiki

I would like to know my options for how best to use WordPress as a wiki. I tried Media Wiki, but the sheer amount of changes I need to make to code to make even trivial changes turned me off. Way off.

Googling doesn't reveal much. What are the best options for using WP as a wiki? (This can be a community question discussing various options.)

In particular, I would like something that addresses:

- Links to non-existing pages actually link to a "create new page" page
- Editing pages without going through /wp-admin/ (i.e. the back-end)
- Searching/listing existing pages when linking (i.e. linking by title, not by URL)

What are my options?

Comment: WordPress is not a wiki, you're mixing two very different styles of content management systems here.  Do you want to run a wiki *on top of* WordPress (using the WP backend to manage things) or *beside* WordPress?

Comment: @EAMann I thought my question would have made that clear; I want to run a Wordpress site as a wiki. That is, to use Wordpress as a base for a wiki. It has the majority of features I need already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress CMS is for blogging you can do this with it but can make something similar like this with your own logics but i recommend you to use other CMS there are many CMS for wiki also check this top 5.

[MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/)

[MoinMoin](http://moinmo.in/)

[PhpWiki](http://phpwiki.sourceforge.net/)

[OddMuseWiki](http://www.oddmuse.org/)

[TikiWiki](http://tiki.org/)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, WordPress is not a wiki.  [Wikis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki) are a fundamentally different form of content management system (where anyone can manage information).  WordPress is meant to *publish* content, wikis are meant to collaboratively *develop* content.

Case-in-point, the WordPress project uses a wiki for [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) documents ... but it runs MediaWiki  rather than WordPress itself to do so.

That said, you certainly *can* use WordPress to power a wiki ... it just won't be easy.

Poking around on Google, I did manage to find these options for you:

- [WordPress Wiki theme](http://wpwikitheme.com/) (linked to by Viruthaigiri)
- [Wiki plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-wiki-plugin/) by WPMU.org (there is a [paid version](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/wordpress-wiki) on their site with a deeper feature set).

Comment: Wordpress is a flexible CMS. It has content (pages), revisioning, multiple concurrent users, all that good stuff. I disagree that it's fundamentally different.

Comment: Flexible, yes. But the workflow for managing content in WordPress is not at all similar to the workflow for managing content on a wiki.  Rather than try to reinvent the wheel, you should stick with another proven solution. As I mentioned before, even the official WordPress site uses MediaWiki to power the Codex.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford $30 you can buy wordpresswiki theme. 
[Check the demo here](http://wpwikitheme.com/)

If you wanna buy it, you can [buy it from here](http://themeforest.net/item/wordpress-wiki-theme/29479)

Comment: It seems like just a theme, no features (like editing from the front page).

Comment: No i'm not affiliated with them. That theme is one of the most popular wordpress theme in themeforest. As of today 846 members purchased that item. $30 is too low for that theme And yes ofcourse it is worth for your $30.

Comment: It's not actually a wiki though, it's a knowledgebase theme.

Answer (score 0):

There area few plugins that extend wiki-functionality to WordPress.

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-wiki-plugin/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-wiki/ (not the same as the above plugin)
- There's some interesting notes on wiki-vs-wordpress @ http://tiki.org/Tiki+vs+WordPress

NOTE: I have not used any of the above plugins, so Your Mileage May Vary.

I'm a big fan of wiki-as-concept for ease-of-use, and use PmWiki to power the main interface to my own site. I also like WordPress (obviously) for different reasons, and miss the PmWiki features when I'm inside of wp-admin [I'm actually developing a plugin to use my wiki as a markup engine inside of WP, but that doesn't give access to the features you're probably looking for, like revision history, links-create-new-pages, etc.]. There are actually some blog-extensions for PmWiki, but none of them match the power of WordPress.

So, that being said -- I may seem to be advocating "use the right tool for the right job", as well.

But in some cases, the right tool ***might be*** a plugin that gives you just the wiki-features you need inside of WordPress.